# Understanding scope and events of Directive in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Suppose if i have a directive like this

```
 app.directive('tablesClick', function () {
     return {
         restrict: 'E',
         template: [
             '<table>',
             '<tr>',
             '<td> <label>This is local value: {{btnval}}</label><br/><input ng-model="btnval" type="text" /><button type="button" ng-click="func()" >reverse</button>',
             '</tr>',
             '</table> '
         ].join(''),
         scope: {
             btnval: '='
         },
         controller: function ($scope, $element) {
             $scope.func = function () {                                              
                 $element;
             };
         },
         link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      }
    }
});
```

Now what i want to do is get the value of the input element on the click of the button, how can i do that.

I just used this logic to understand the working of scope and event handling in directive. thank you

Comment: `$scope.func = function(){ var myValue = $scope.btnval; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values assigned in the template as model can be accessed as part of scope in `Controller` and `link` functions

```
app.directive('tablesClick', function () {
     return {
         restrict: 'E',
         template: [
             '<table>',
             '<tr>',
             '<td> <label>This is local value: {{btnval}}</label><br/><input ng-model="btnval" type="text" /><button type="button" ng-click="func()" >reverse</button>',
             '</tr>',
             '</table> '
         ].join(''),
         scope: {
             btnval: '='
         },
         controller: function ($scope, $element) {
             $scope.func = function () {                                              
                 console.log($scope.btnval); // this is the desired value
             };
         },
         link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: suppose if i want to bind a click event to a element in the directive, then can i do that inside the controller?

Comment: The `link: function(scope, element, attributes){ }` is used to peform DOM related operation in Angular JS. Here you `element` is whole template you provided in the directive definition.

Comment: thank you for your answer,it was very helpful to me.. my question is when i use this 
  link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    element.find('input[type="text"]').bind('click', function () {
                        alert('you have clicked me');
                    });

                }
i am not able to bind the element

Comment: if i am understanding your question right, you should bind events in `link` function and all `value binding` model preparation should be done in controller.

Comment: so can you help me with the code and how to do it.. thank you